# Qustion about config of level0.dirs.quota and alluxio.user.file.write.tier.default in Alluxio

Tags: alluxio

I set level0.dirs.quota=1GB, level1.dirs.quota=10GB and alluxio.user.file.write.tier.default=1.
Then when I use alluxio-fuse to write files over 1G, it will fail. But if I use ./bin/alluxio fs copyFromLocal to write files over 1G, it will success.

The configuration is as follows:

```
alluxio.worker.tieredstore.levels=2
alluxio.worker.tieredstore.level0.alias=MEM
alluxio.worker.tieredstore.level0.dirs.path=/Volumes/ramdisk
alluxio.worker.tieredstore.level0.dirs.quota=1GB
alluxio.worker.tieredstore.level0.watermark.high.ratio=0.9
alluxio.worker.tieredstore.level0.watermark.low.ratio=0.7
alluxio.worker.tieredstore.level1.alias=HDD
alluxio.worker.tieredstore.level1.dirs.path=/tmp
alluxio.worker.tieredstore.level1.dirs.quota=10GB
alluxio.worker.tieredstore.level1.watermark.high.ratio=0.9
alluxio.worker.tieredstore.level1.watermark.low.ratio=0.7

alluxio.user.file.write.tier.default=1
```

I used alluxio-fuse command to re-mount, then I can use alluxio-fuse to write files over 1G.

Is it necessary to re-mount after changing alluxio.user config?

However, although I can write files over 1G after setting alluxio.user.file.write.tier.default=1, reading files over 1G will fail.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

For your first question: Is it necessary to re-mount after changing alluxio.user config?
The answer is Yes! Please re-mount Alluxio-Fuse every time you change any alluxio user configuration.

Could you provide more information about reading files over 1G will fail?
Which Alluxio version you are using?
Could you attach your Alluxio logs if possible, especially the logs/fuse.log?